# Write russian symbols in ini file with NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

I have several UTF8-BOM ini-files and using Unicode nsis installer.

Using WriteINIStr is working great with latin symbols, but russian symbols are not displayed.

For example this code is not working:

```
WriteINIStr $File "TestSection" "Test" "Тест"
```

I have a few thoughts about encoding file into UTF16 and backwards, but I don't think that's the right path.

Answer (score 0):

If the .ini has a UTF-16LE BOM the Windows ini functions will write to the file with UTF-16 encoding.

```
FileOpen $0 $INSTDIR\file.ini a
FileWriteUTF16LE /BOM $0 ""
FileClose $0
WriteIniStr $INSTDIR\file.ini foo bar "${U+2115}SIS"
```

As long as other programs that access this file also uses the standard Windows ini functions this will work. If the other programs uses custom parser functions that require UTF-8 then this will not work and you have to [convert](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Unicode_plug-in) the file encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, an app is using the parser which doesn't support UTF-16, so ini-files should only be using UTF-8 encoding.